# What is a good way to store a persistent array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` of objects that I would like to persist between user sessions. Each object has an `NSInteger` property, and I would like to be able to access all of the objects for calculations using that property (averages, mins, maxes, etc.)

Would it be better to store that array into a Core Data database or just store my objects individually into the database?

EDIT: The array should hold no more than 1,000 items.

Comment: is this a *lot* of data (which would probably be better in Core Data) or is it just a *little* data (which can be easily written out to a plist file or NSUserDefaults)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I edited my question. I don't plan on the array to be more than 1,000 objects.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size. If it's simple just archive the array to a file

**Edited to add**

If all you want to persist is an array you don't need to use the archiver methods, you can do it directly.

Imagine you have a file URL in your app's Documents directory called `persistentURL` which you want to use to save and read your array from.

All you need to do to persist the array is:

```
[yourArray writeToURL:persistentURL atomically:YES];
```

And when you want to read the data back into an array it's as simple as:

```
yourArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:persistentURL];
```

You can use this method here because the array contains only `NSNumbers` which are property list objects (i.e. objects that can be put directly into a plist).

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. The array will not be more than 1,000 elements in length.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray and NSMutableArray can't contain integers directly. It has to contain NSNumber objects.

Anyway, I'd just use NSCoding. Try the methods archiveRootObject:toFile: (which writes directly to a file) or archivedDataWithRootObject (which converts the content to a byte-stream in NSData).

For <=1000 items it should be fast enough.

If you're reading and writing the array enough, you might want to consider using a malloc'ed C array of "long"s, and saving that as bytes to a file. That would be faster, and you could read/write values to your C array easily, instead of having to do object replacement. On the other hand resizing the array or inserting values is a pain with a C array, and you also have to be aware of data size and byte ordering issues if you will ever transfer this data between devices.

Edit: I just wrote a little test, and writing an NSArray of 1,000 NSNumbers to a file with archiveRootObject:toFile: takes about 0.0038 seconds on on old iPhone 4 I have around for testing. That's the slowest machine that supports iOS 7, and it's 3.8 THOUSANDTHS of a second, to write 1,000 items. So writing an array of 10,000 items should take 3.8 hundredths of a second or less.

Unless you are reading and writing this array many times a second in a loop, using archiveRootObject:toFile: is plenty fast enough.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would use the following to store that array:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray ForKey:@"myArray"]
```

and retrieve it anywhere in the app:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myArray"] mutableCopy];
```

That seems to me to be the easiest way to persist that data. You can store the mutable array in NSUser defaults, and I believe you'll need to create a mutable copy of it when you retrieve it later on to be able to continue to make changes to it.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not a good choice for persistent 1000 NSNumbers.